# Import image cells from excel to Google Sheet

Tags: excel, image, google-apps-script

I am trying to import some product datas from Excel to Google Sheet. There are some pictures in excel. If I simply copy and paste the pictures will be missing out. With Google Sheet's import function, the images will appear in Google sheet just as they do in excel.

However, most of the pictures are "over the cell". I want them to be "in the cell" so it is easier to manipulate the pictures later.

I don't know why SOME of the product pictures appear to be "in the cell" in google sheet.
The screenshot below is from Excel, the two selected pictures are inserted into excel in the same way:

[image]

And this is a screenshot from Google Sheet:

[image]

You can see in the last row the picture is "in the cell".
If there is a way to ensure the pictures to be "in the cell" after the import, my problem will be solved. But I can't find out how.

So I am thinking if I can use App Script to do this, the steps I can think of are:

1. Loop through the images
2. If they are "over the cell", detect which cell they are over
3. Put the image into the cell

Is this possible at all?

A sample of my data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OtlQNu7cKelnXBJk2gdCXHJkT0ixNugXfaBkQfQzxto/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share a copy/sample of your spreadsheet so we can replicate. Remove sensitive data if any

Comment: @Logan Question updated.

Comment: how are the pictures being put in the cell? I am unable to see the formula you are using. Are you manually copying and pasting them?

Answer (score 2):

### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, there is no built-in method for directly retrieving the image in a cell using Google Apps Script. So, in this case, I would like to propose using DocsServiceApp (Author: me) of a Google Apps Script library. When this library is used, the image in a cell can be retrieved, and also it can confirm whether the image is put on a cell or into a cell. When this library is used as a sample script for achieving your goal, how about the following sample script?

### Usage:

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

Please install DocsServiceApp of a Google Apps Script library. You can see how to install it at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp#how-to-install).

#### 2. Enable Drive API.

Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

#### 3. Prepare sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your sample Spreadsheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const obj = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(ss.getId()).getSheetByName("test").getImages();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");
  obj.forEach(o => {
    if (!o.image.innerCell) {
      const temp = DriveApp.createFile(o.image.blob);
      const link = Drive.Files.get(temp.getId()).thumbnailLink.replace("=s220", "=s1000");
      sheet.getRange(o.range.a1Notation).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(link).build());
      temp.setTrashed(true);
    }
  });
  sheet.getImages().forEach(e => e.remove());
}
```

- When this script is run, the images over the cells are put into the cells.

### Note:

- I tested my script using your provided sample Spreadsheet. If you change your Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

### Reference:

- [DocsServiceApp (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> It works on my test sheet. However when I try to run it on my actual sheet, I am running into this error:

Although, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation, from your error message, I added one more sample script by guessing your current situation. Could you please confirm it?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const tempSS = DriveApp.getFileById(ssId).makeCopy("temp");
  const obj = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(tempSS.getId()).getSheetByName("test").getImages();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");
  obj.forEach(o => {
    if (!o.image.innerCell) {
      const temp = DriveApp.createFile(o.image.blob);
      const link = Drive.Files.get(temp.getId()).thumbnailLink.replace("=s220", "=s1000");
      sheet.getRange(o.range.a1Notation).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(link).build());
      temp.setTrashed(true);
    }
  });
  sheet.getImages().forEach(e => e.remove());
  tempSS.setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: Great library. I haven't tried it but it opens a new door for me. I will try it and let you know if I encounter any problem.

Comment: @shenkwen Thank you for replying. I tested this sample script using your provided Spreadsheet. So, I would like to recommend testing it using your provided Spreadsheet.

Comment: It works on my test sheet. However when I try to run it on my actual sheet, I am running into this error: https://imgur.com/a/UWkbTZF

Comment: @shenkwen Thank you for replying. About `It works on my test sheet.`, I confirmed it. About `However when I try to run it on my actual sheet, I am running into this error:`, I apologize for the inconvenience. But, my proposed script is for your sample Spreadsheet. By this, I cannot replicate your situation. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: @shenkwen By guessing your situation, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide your new sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I've found what caused the error in my sheet. It is very interesting, turns out it has to do with the color of a parenthese. Please watch this video: https://www.loom.com/share/4254cf14032c40b0806554a7d607a7cd. And the test sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fvm38tRWo2R6pWkeSNgyPMpl-42-gKouSR5hNoj88X0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @shenkwen Thank you for replying and providing the new sample Spreadsheet. From your new sample Spreadsheet, I updated my library. So, please remove the library once, reinstall the library, and then, test it using your new sample Spreadsheet, again. In that case, please use my 1st sample script.